# How long until new cat settled in (going on holiday)

Tags: cats, new-pets

Recently we were considering getting a cat from someone who was leaving the country. But we were afraid the cat would not get enough time to settle in at our house before we left to go on holiday for a week.

Generaly, what are rules of thumb when planning to get a cat, how long should one allow the cat to get used to the house before planning to leave for a week?
What about a longer holiday of 3 weeks?

In all cases, the cat would be allowed to go outside, and during the week of our absence others would feed and look in on the cat.

Next time we have the opportunity to get a cat we would really love to.

Comment: Hard to tell, it depends on the cat. We've had one that settled in after a week or so, another took months

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend not letting the cat outside until they are certain that this is their new home. (Actually these days I'd hesitate to let the cat out unsupervised at all, but I'm not dogmatic -- catmatic? -- about that.) It's also a lot easier for the cat-sitter if they know the cat will be in the house.

How long it takes to settle in is up to the cat, really. It is probably easier, and easier to learn the house rules, if life is more predictable, so if possible I'd hold off adopting until you expect to be home for a few months.